# Does Mass Suggestion spell end if the caster dies?

Tags: dnd-5e, character-death, charmed

Unlike regular *Suggestion*, *Mass Suggestion* does not require concentration nor does it require the caster to be in particular range after the spell has been invoked.

What would happen if the caster of *Mass Suggestion* was to die between it being cast and before the spell ends (e.g. if the caster used his last action to cast the spell before succumbing to a wound).

Comment: Hey Mark! It looks like we have another question that has already asked the same thing in a more general way. Does it answer your question? If not, let us know what aspect is missing from that Q&A and/or [edit] it into your question and we might be able to reopen it :)